# EXTJS: How can I add an click event on Icon node in a Tree Panel

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, icons, treepanel

I try to get an event click on the node's Icon in a tree panel.

I have a tree with many node and in front of the leaf node, I have an Icon.
For the moment, when I click on a node I display a PDF file.

I want to do a specific action when I click on the Icon of this node.

Someone have an idea for do that?

Thanks a lot for your futur answers!

EDIT:
Thanks for your answer,

@Hown_: Ok, but I must do an specific action which depends to the select node. With a CSS selector, I can't do that. I'm wrong?

@budgw: Yes, it's a good solution, but my icon must be in front of the text node :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest way would be to add `itemclick` event to your `TreePanel` and check in the handler fn if the tree icon was clicked by checking the target of the event. It works as simple as this:

You may have to change the css selector of the `getTarget` fn for your specific use. ( e.g. only leaf elements or pdf icons or something like that )

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "detention",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "homework",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "book report",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "alegrbra",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "buy lottery tickets",
                leaf: true
            }]
        }
    });    

    Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        width: 200,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        listeners: {
            itemclick: function(treeModel, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
                var iconElClicked = e.getTarget('.x-tree-icon');

                if(iconElClicked){
                    //tree icon clicked 

                    //do something in here
                    console.log('tree icon clicked');
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with the icon in front of the node (maybe I'm wrong).

But I usually solve this kind of use case by using a treepanel with 2 columns :

- a treecolumn
- an action column like in this example [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-grid).

The trick is to use the config property 'hideHeaders:true' on the tree panel to make it looks like a classic tree.

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution, but my icon must be in front of the text node :(

Answer (score 0):

You can select the dom elements of the icons via css selector and add a click event after the render method.

here is an example: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8kd

**UPDATE:**

exmaple:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "detention",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "homework",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "book report",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "alegrbra",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "buy lottery tickets",
                leaf: true
            }]
        }
    });

    Ext.define('MyPanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        width: 200,

        onTreeIconClick: function(treeModel, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
            // DO SOMETHING IN HERE    
            console.log('onTreeIconClicked');
        },

        render: function(){                
            this.callParent(arguments);

            var domEls = this.el.dom.querySelectorAll('#' + this.getId() + ' .x-tree-icon', this.el.dom);

            for(var i = 0; i<domEls.length; i++){
                Ext.get(domEls[i]).on('click', function(){                    
                    //click on tree icon

                    this.on('itemclick', this.onTreeIconClick, this, { single: true });                                                     

                }, this);
            }           

        }
    });


    Ext.create('MyPanel', {

        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    });
});
```

Comment: u can also change the selector in my example. e.g. to only select your pdf icons

Comment: Ok, but I must do an specific action which depends to the select node. With a CSS selector, I can't do that. I'm wrong?

Comment: i updated the fiddle. i just added a single select event on the TreePanel - which will be fired right after our click event ;) Now you can access the selected record in this function.

Comment: sorry - the select event is not the right one ( would be buggy with it ) you have to use the itemclick event. Updated Fiddle again. Now it works.

Comment: It's a good way!
But it never enter to the click event.
Ext.get(domEls[i]).on('click', function(){                    
           //click on tree icon
           
           this.on('select', this.onTreeIconClick, this, { single: true });                                            
           
          }, this);
Never enter in that and so no event on the tree is defined and I don't understand why :( Can you help me?

Comment: are you sure that your css selector is correct? is your `domEls` array empty? If not: please provide a sourcecode via pastebin or something of your render fn. If it is empty: check your css selector. You know how to do that? what classes are given at your icon tag?